# Python compute average value of key in series of JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, series

I have a `pandas.core.series.Series` where each element is a JSON as shown

```
0     {"count": 157065, "grp": {"a1": 12, "a2": 32}}
1     {"count": 2342, "grp": {"a1": 4, "a2": 34}}
2     {"count": 543, "grp": {"a1": 1, "a2": 11}}
3     {"count": 156, "grp": {"a1": 56, "a2": 75}}
```

How to compute the average value of `count` in all the JSONs and also compute the average value of `a1` and `a2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure whether this is what you were asking for.

This is for calculating the average of "count"

```
doc1 = {"count": 157065, "grp": {"a1": 12, "a2": 32}}
doc2 = {"count": 2342, "grp": {"a1": 4, "a2": 34}}
doc3 = {"count": 543, "grp": {"a1": 1, "a2": 11}}
doc4 = {"count": 156, "grp": {"a1": 56, "a2": 75}}
lojs = [doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4] # list of all the jsons

countaverage = 0
# For every json, it gets the count and adds it to the variable I defined
for j in lojs:
    countaverage += j["count"]
# Divides it by the length of the amount of documents
countaverage = countaverage/len(lojs)
```

And if you wanted to get the average of a1 with or instead of the one above, you could use this code:

```
a1average = 0
for j in lojs:
    a1average += j["grp"]["a1"] # getting "a1" inside of "grp"
a1average = a1average/len(lojs)
```

and you could just swap a1 out for a2 if wanted to get a2

**EXTENSION For documents that might have different amount of "a"s:**

```
doc1 = {"count": 157065, "grp": {"a1": 12, "a2": 32}}
doc2 = {"count": 2342, "grp": {"a1": 4, "a2": 34}}
doc3 = {"count": 543, "grp": {"a1": 1, "a2": 11, "a3": 46, "a4": 23}}
doc4 = {"count": 156, "grp": {"a1": 56, "a2": 75, "a3": 23}}
lojs = [doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4]

grps = [] # defining a list that will contain all of the "a"s
for doc in lojs: # getting each document in the list of documents
    for a in doc["grp"].keys(): # getting all the keys in the grp of that document
        if a not in grps: # checking whether the "a" already exists in the list of "a"s
            grps.append(a) # adding the new "a" to the list

averages = {} # using a dict instead of a list because it will be containing multiple values
for grp in grps: # getting each "a"
    averages[grp] = [0, 0] # setting the value of that "a" to zero

for grp in grps: # getting each "a"
    for doc in lojs: # getting each document
        if grp in doc["grp"].keys(): # getting every "a" in the grp of the document
            averages[grp][0] += doc["grp"][grp] # adding the value of that a to the corresponding value/key (idk dude) in the dictionary
            averages[grp][1] += 1 # increasing the amount the "a" has been mentioned by 1

for el in averages: # getting each average
    averages[el][0] = averages[el][0]/averages[el][1] # dividing b
```

And you can get the value of each average using

`averages["a3"][0]`

Of course, you can change "a3" to whichever "a" you want.
Btw, if it isn't clear, you are getting the first element because the value of that key is a list that contains both the averaged (idk if that's a word) value and the amount of times the "a" has occurred inside your documents.

This probably isn't the most efficient way, but I mean, it works!

Comment: Could you also update your answer to handle the general case where there may be multiple and variable number of keys in `grp`, say `doc1` has `a1,a2,a3`, `doc2` has `a1,a3` and `doc3` has `a2,a3`, then `a1average ` would be calculated accordingly, where it is present.

Comment: Done! Hope my code helps you out!